# Find which merge strategy has been used for a merge commit?

Tags: git, git-merge

Let's take a simple example, where I merge a topic branch into master using the merge strategy "ours". This merge creates the H commit, and after I do some other commits.

```
      A---B---C topic
     /         \
D---E---F---G---H---I---J---K master
```

I would like to know, if it is possible to determine afterwards which merge strategy was used  on the commit H ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, that’s not possible – git does not store such metadata. You can store such information in the commit message, but that’s completely up to the user.

You can make a good guess about the merge strategy by looking at how the conflicts where resolved:

```
git log -p -c -1 YOURMERGE
```